# How to remove unwanted lines/connections in plotly::ggplotly() animation?

Tags: r, plotly, r-sf, ggplotly

I've created an animation using the plotly library which calls a ggplot with `geom_sf()` layers. When I run the animation I get weird, random lines or connections between unconnected points in the map layer that I don't want.[image: Animation showing unwanted connecting lines]

I saw a [post suggesting the order of the points matters](https://community.plot.ly/t/scatterplot-lines-unwanted-connecting/8729) (i.e. should be ordered by x ascending) but I tried ordering the points and still experience the issue.

I've created a MRE; when you load the 'scotland.html' file in your browser it should display similar behaviour:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("sf")
library("ggplot2")
library("plotly")
library("htmlwidgets")

tmp <- tempdir()
tmpfile <- paste0(tmp, "/scotland.zip")
url <- "https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/Scotland_ol_1991.zip"
download.file(url, tmpfile)
unzip(tmpfile, exdir = tmp)

scotland <- read_sf(tmp, "scotland_ol_1991")

points <- data.frame(
  id = 20:1,
  year = 20:1,
  east = sample(7459:469817, size = 20),
  north = sample(530297:1219574, size = 20)
)

points <-
  points %>%
  uncount(year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(year = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()

# Try rearranging by x coordinate as suggested by this post:
# https://community.plot.ly/t/scatterplot-lines-unwanted-connecting/8729/3
scotland_order =
  scotland %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  st_coordinates() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(L2) %>%
  summarise(min_x = min(X))

scotland =
  scotland %>%
  mutate(order = scotland_order$min_x) %>%
  arrange(order) %>%
  select(-order)

points <- st_as_sf(points, coords = c("east", "north"))
points <- st_set_crs(points, 27700)

p <- ggplotly(
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = scotland) +
    geom_sf(data = points, aes(frame = year, ids = id))
)

saveWidget(p, "scotland.html")
```

I don't think it's a problem with the data (i.e. the `scotland` layer) because:

- Not all animation frames are affected
- If you run the animation, go back, and play it again it doesn't show the weird behaviour

Any suggestions about what's going on, how to solve it, or any workarounds greatly received!

Comment: Hm, not sure whether just adapting the order might help here. Could be a bug in ggplotly. Did you consider using native plotly instead?

Comment: @wusel I didn't think ordering the data would solve it either, but figured it would be worth a try. I was hoping to not have to learn native plotly syntax as it's already in `R`, but maybe I'll need to